# JHipster without database but still with the possibility to generate entitys

Tags: database, microservices, jhipster, generate

Is it possible to create a JHipster project without a database and use **instead** of this persistenz-layer a **third party** framework? I already saw the possibility to create a JHipster microservice without a database but then you can’t generate any pojos, controllers with CRUD functionality or services.

So is there any **solution/workaround** how to generate those microservices without any database **but still** with those necessary classes?

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

The entity generator and JDL don't support creating entities without database but you could use [API-First development](https://www.jhipster.tech/doing-api-first-development/) and describe your API in YAML to generate code though it does create only interfaces not implementations and also will not generate frontend.